# Prove Taylor's theorem for n=1 using fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

So I have been trying to prove Taylor's theorem using the fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$ f(t) = f(a) +  \int_{a}^{t} f'(x) dx $$
Continuing, we can find the same for $ f'(x) $:
$$ f'(x) = f'(a) +  \int_{a}^{x} f''(x_0) dx_0 $$

Let's now set that into the first expression:
$$ f(t) = f(a) +  \int_{a}^{t} \left( f'(a) +  \int_{a}^{x} f''(x_0) dx_0 \right) dx $$
Let's also abuse the fact that integration is linear, and that we are integrating for x and not a at $f'(a)$

$$ f(t) = f(a) + f'(a) \int_{a}^{t} 1 dx + \int_{a}^{t} \int_{a}^{x} f''(x_0) dx_0 dx $$

$$ f(t) = f(a) + f'(a) (t-a) + \int_{a}^{t} \int_{a}^{x} f''(x_0) dx_0 dx $$

So far, so good, it seems to match with Taylor's theorem. What I'm having issue with is the last part $ \int_{a}^{t} \int_{a}^{x} f''(x_0) dx_0 dx $
Is there anything we can do with that?
Our professor came with the following formula:
$$ f(t) = f(a) + f'(a)(t-a) + \int_{a}^{t} (t-s) f''(x)dx $$
Would that correspond to what I got? Or how would I go from mine to that one?

Comment: 1) yes that's the error term (for $n=1$) in integral form; 2) you can keep iterating

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's good to hear (especially for the exam). How do I integrate having double integrals left though?

Answer (score 1):

By changing the order of integration (and adjusting the bounds of integration accordingly), we can get
$$ \int_{x=a}^{x=t}\int_{x_0=a}^{x_0=x} f''(x_0) \, dx_0 dx = \int_{x_0=a}^{x_0=t}\int_{x=x_0}^{x=t} f''(x_0)\, dx dx_0 = \int_a^t (t - x_0)f''(x_0)\, dx_0.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one quick question to that, I see you swapped the integrals, but I'm wondering why the $x=a$ in the first one changed to $x=x_0$ when swapped? (and the other integral changed from $x_0 = x$ to $x_0=t$)

Comment: You're welcome! When you swap the order of integration, you have to make sure that you are integrating over the same region as originally intended. The easiest way to see why the bounds are correct is to draw the original region and verify that the region used when the order of integration is swapped coincides with the original. For reference, the region should be a right triangle with side lengths $t-a$ translated by $(a,a)$ away from the origin.